# Jmeter throws "org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException"

Tags: performance, jmeter

We use Jmeter to do performance testing. I gave 10 threads(10 users) with ramp up time 60 secs, 4 out 10 users failing to logout getting org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond

Our script works this way. User logs in, access list page and do one submit operation and access the details page of the submit. Every user does three times and logs out. When I have just one time instead three time it works well, But when I configure the script to do for three times then I face above mentioned error.

Im not really not sure is it some thing related to Jmeter settings or server settings?

Answer (score 3):

You asked, "Is it something related to Jmeter settings or server settings?", but I am going to answer a slightly different question, i.e. "Where should I do now?"

You might start by confirming that your test is valid, i.e. that your test is interacting with the server is a legitimate way.  You haven't said whether the server needs to support ten simultaneous users, or whether your server is configured the way it will be configured in production, or whether your server is working with the same kind of data that it will use in production.

My best guess is that the submit operation is slow, but the problem you described is hard to diagnose without understanding what the server does and how it is configured.  Based on what you wrote, I assume you are primarily a tester rather than a developer.  If that's true, find a developer who is willing to work with you on this.

You might ask the developer what other information they need.  They might ask you to try monitoring the CPU utilization on the server.  If you have access to the server logs, they might ask you to try running your test with just one thread, while watching the server logs.  Sometimes the server logs can help you narrow down which part of an operation takes the most time.  They might also try monitoring the server log while running with all 10 threads -- you may have an error message that will help solve the problem.

They might also want to know how to run your JMeter test themselves, so you might think about whether your test contains any dependencies that would make it hard to run the test on a different machine, e.g. external files or hard-coded directory paths.

Comment: Actually Submit operation is not slow and we get 90% response in around 4 secs which is good. we have checked CPU utilization, Server logs and there are no errors in that. We just suspect nginx settings which is on between load balancer and application. whether nginx restricts the http connections. But nginx also correct configs. No idea what happens

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [View Results Tree Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) to inspect what exact responses are being sent? I know that it consumes lots of resources, but it should be capable of dealing with 10 concurrent threads in GUI mode.

If you rely on correlation and parametrization it would be also good to add a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to see JMeter Variables and Properties values.

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) for more clues.

Comment: I checked in View Results tree, It says no response code. That's where I confused

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same issue for some time and tired java option in Client Implementation (Advanced Option in Http Request ) and its working fine completely . Try this option for solution to solve this issue in failing request. [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Similar question:**

[Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond: Is my server failing to handle load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943565/168205)

**Summary**

> If you upgraded recently to JMeter 2.10 or 2.11, you may have noticed
>   increased errors of this type:
>
> ```
> Socket closed
>
> Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException (the target server failed to respond)
> ```
>
> The increase of this type of errors can be explained by two settings
>   changes:
>
> ```
> retry of failing request (idempotent ones only) has been disabled in JMeter 2.10
>
> stale check in HTTP Client 3 and 4 implementations has been disabled in JMeter 2.11
> ```